# Display input textbox from selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, radio-button, display

I want to display an input textbox after choosing one of the radio button selection but I'm having difficulty to do it. For example, I have 3 radio buttons: name, age and phone number. If I choose the name, then the input textbox will display for me to input a name and so on if I choose others. I want to know how to do it using HTML and javascript. Mind to help me, anyone? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? paste you html/javascript code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text box to appear when a radio button is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202952/text-box-to-appear-when-a-radio-button-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

you can write all things like this.

```js
function show(gender){
  console.log(gender);
}
```

```html
<label for="gender">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="show('male')" value="male"/> male <br />
  <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="show('female')" vlaue="female"/>  Female
</label>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="name">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="createElements()"/> Male <br />
  <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="createElements()"/> Female
  
  <div id="input"></div>
</label>

<script>
function createElements(){
 var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  document.getElementById("input").appendChild(input);
}
</script>
```